# How list new files created in a commit?

Tags: git

I'd like to list all new files in a commit, I am trying the following command, but it is not filtering by commit, it is returning all commits.

```
git whatchanged --diff-filter=A --pretty=format: bc895ad6a411683f5737d4a4b89e52f54cd2d68c
```

Comment: Why use `git whatchanged`? Its use [is not recommended](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged), it's `git log` in disguise. For one commit you want to use [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show).

Comment: `git show --summary --pretty= --name-status`

Comment: Thank you. I got it using git show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, the command bellow do precisely what I want.

```
git show <hash> --name-status --diff-filter=A
```